# HttpWebRequest, WebResponse and WebBrowser Differents

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, html-agility-pack, httpwebresponse

I have winform application and I am scraping HTML.Sometimes google redirect me captcha page for verifying.

And problem starting here I am using HtmlAgilityPack and getting html like :

```
 try
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36";
            request.Timeout = 10000;
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                return reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
           //Here I am getting captcha page
            using (var sr = new StreamReader(e.Response.GetResponseStream()))
                return sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
```

after loading html to my HtmlDocument. I am looking for captcha. If html contains, I am opening WebBrowser and navigating same url again.I am verifying cathpa and "thats it" google is open. But after 30 second, if I try getting html again. It shows me captcha page again. I test it, WebBrowser doesnt show capthca page anymore but my request is still showing  **WHY** ? They both request from same localhost same computer same wifi ..

```
 var webBrowser1 = new WebBrowser
                     {
                         ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true,
                         AllowNavigation = true,
                         Dock = DockStyle.Fill
                     };
                    BrowserSettings(webBrowser1);

              webBrowser1.Refresh(WebBrowserRefreshOption.Completely);
            //Here I am NOT getting captcha page
                    webBrowser1.Navigate(searchUrl);
                    if (DialogForms == null)
                    {
                        DialogForms = new Form
                        {
                            WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized,
                            TopMost = true
                        };
                    }
                    DialogForms.Controls.Add(webBrowser1);
                    DialogForms.ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat quick non-answer: Because what you're doing is pretty much why [reCAPTCHA](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/v3beta.html) exists and helps mitigate and/or prevent (emphasis mine):

> reCAPTCHA uses an *advanced risk analysis engine and adaptive CAPTCHAs* to **keep automated software** from engaging in abusive activities on your site.
>
> ...it uses advanced risk analysis techniques, considering the user’s entire engagement with the CAPTCHA, and evaluates a broad range of cues **that distinguish humans from bots**.

---

Update:

Q:

> *but my question is, how can understand reCAPTCHA my request method. Example I get the html by WebBrowser or via Request:Response and read from Stream.İt doesnt show reCAPTCHA for WebBrowser but for Request:Response it does*

A:

- The "bot check" runs based on it's own determination on when to invoke it.
- I also *assumed* that the site you're scraping is implementing Google's reCAPTCHA *specifically* - that's my mistake. The site could very well be behind a `WAF` ([Web Application Firewall](https://www.google.com/search?q=Web+Application+Firewall)) service which will invoke bot checks that offer some challenge based on CAPTCHA (or outright reject the request).

Hth...

Comment: From your answer, what I understand is, it's normal if reCAPTCHA appear for both. True?

Comment: but my question is, how can understand reCAPTCHA  my request method. Example I get the html by WebBrowser or via Request:Response and read from Stream.İt doesnt show reCAPTCHA for WebBrowser but for Request:Response it does.They are in the same solution same project same Form.